# PHP conditional test func call against two values

Tags: php, coding-style, code-quality

I was wondering if there's a one liner for `PHP` that would allow me test multiple  values against a function call. As example, say I want to test if `foo()` returns either 1 or 2, (in pseudo code)

```
if( [1||2]==foo() );
```

Maybe above is a bad example of what I mean. Currently if I want to test two values against a function call I would use:

```
$test = foo();
if( 1==$test || 2==$test );
```

Its these two lines that I would like to simplify into one

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing like that in PHP, however you can go for something like this -- even tho I'm not really recommending it:

```
if ( in_array(foo(), array(1, 2), true) ) ...
```

Please note that it's not gonna work on `&&` conditions and you're limited only to `==` and `===`.

Answer (score -1):

In the specific example given this would work:

```
if ( abs( foo() - 1.5 ) == 0.5 )
```

This works for two number values, but for the obvious reasons is not very easy to generalise